# The curious case of high 5 min load average

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, load

Looking for some expert advice here. I'm a first time sys admin on my own server and I can't figure the bottle neck in my server.

Linux CentOS 6 Apache 2.4 PHP 5.5

I've been receiving tons of high 5 min load average alert ranging between 8 - 80 from CSF

So I went ahead and installed sqltuner on my server and let it run for 3 days

The results don't show anything out of the ordinary but I'm still getting high 5 min load average daily

I'm trying to find the bottle neck (CPU, load caused by out of memory issues or I/O-bound load)

Would be stoked if someone can share any insights...

(I've included sqltuner's report and the high load email output below)

```
-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!
-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 120d 18h 27m 20s (227M q [21.795 qps], 51M conn, TX: 907B, RX: 26B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 38% / 62%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Total buffers: 15.4G global + 4.1M per thread (600 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 16.2G (51.75% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 17.8G (56.91% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (11/227M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 33% (199/600)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.56%  (284327/51183230)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 83.0% (78M cached / 94M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 10288
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (392 temp sorts / 1M sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 4% (65K on disk / 1M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (199 created / 51M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 22% (425 open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (433/50K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (41M immediate / 41M locks)
-------- MyISAM Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 20.2% (108M used / 536M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 512.0M/14.7M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.8% (51M cached / 121K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 40.8% (4M cached / 2M writes)
-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 14.6G/140.9M
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 3.39% (32546 used/ 959999 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (5437258684 hits/ 5437259670 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 24069213 writes)
-------- AriaDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.
-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Increasing the query_cache size over 128M may reduce performance
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 128M) [see warning above]
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=14)
----------------------
(The only change I've made is to reduce InnoDB size and add multiple pool instances)
```

The high daily load email:

```
Time:                    Sun Dec  6 05:43:53 2015 -0500
1 Min Load Avg:          80.26
5 Min Load Avg:          21.19
15 Min Load Avg:         7.46
Running/Total Processes: 221/875
ps.txt
O
Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
Srv    PID    Acc    M    CPU     SS    Req    Conn    Child    Slot    Client    VHost    Request
0-1424    16243    0/149/2713129    W     1.28    14    0    0.0    2.34    65107.59     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
1-1424    17057    0/18/2701770    W     2.15    4    0    0.0    0.30    62402.50     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
2-1424    17064    0/24/2685073    W     2.11    13    0    0.0    0.32    62668.14     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
3-1424    15319    0/215/2657841    W     3.50    4    0    0.0    3.88    61950.21     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
4-1424    11567    0/204/2651294    W     7.10    7    0    0.0    3.00    63562.61     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
5-1424    16512    0/37/2640191    W     2.19    5    0    0.0    0.60    63637.48     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
6-1424    17735    0/8/2630311    W     0.62    19    0    0.0    0.06    65036.68     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
7-1424    16521    0/31/2613938    W     2.20    19    0    0.0    0.36    62385.07     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
8-1424    16081    0/33/2611913    W     2.46    5    0    0.0    0.42    60535.12     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
9-1424    14711    0/120/2603042    W     1.89    18    0    0.0    2.11    59868.26     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
10-1424    16838    0/21/2592501    W     1.77    15    0    0.0    0.24    62195.33     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
11-1424    16531    0/42/2584776    W     2.45    11    0    0.0    0.39    62253.11     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
12-1424    17065    0/20/2570161    W     1.29    12    0    0.0    0.18    60474.65     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
13-1424    17770    0/13/2564128    W     1.27    2    0    0.0    0.63    59748.24     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
14-1424    17771    0/14/2542936    W     1.30    2    0    0.0    0.17    60513.73     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
15-1424    15736    0/64/2536855    W     2.91    7    0    0.0    1.16    61453.61     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
16-1424    17077    0/19/2522131    W     2.76    15    0    0.0    0.35    59307.60     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
17-1424    14723    0/93/2521068    W     3.38    6    0    0.0    1.77    60437.40     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
18-1424    16279    0/62/2509938    W     1.81    15    0    0.0    1.07    61401.24     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
19-1424    15333    0/116/2498356    W     3.24    19    0    0.0    1.69    57911.45     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
20-1424    16297    1/35/2494463    W     0.98    53    62    16.1    0.47    59474.66     58.174.24.65    suspensionrevolution.com:80    GET /new/wp-content/themes/optimizePressTheme/lib/assets/defaul
21-1424    16298    0/40/2473943    W     3.83    3    0    0.0    0.54    57987.71     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
22-1424    18054    0/6/2469193    W     1.23    1    0    0.0    0.05    59122.65     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
23-1424    12894    0/162/2458774    W     5.90    17    0    0.0    2.42    56404.92     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
24-1424    18088    0/4/2452422    W     0.90    11    0    0.0    0.00    58405.08     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
25-1424    18089    0/6/2446570    W     1.22    1    0    0.0    0.03    57036.34     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
26-1424    17079    0/30/2439491    W     1.88    0    0    0.0    0.43    54697.67     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
27-1424    16101    0/64/2416961    W     1.53    18    0    0.0    1.69    57160.43     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
28-1424    18140    0/9/2403931    W     0.62    18    0    0.0    0.02    55901.03     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
29-982    1505    1/18/1548355    G     0.14    2914733    450294    2.8    0.29    34947.04     96.47.70.4    suspensionrevolution.com:80    POST /dap/dap-clickbank-6.0.php HTTP/1.1
30-1424    15338    0/100/2384316    W     2.20    7    0    0.0    1.24    53919.77     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
31-1424    16300    2/56/2379897    K     3.47    3    1365    2.4    1.01    55195.75     89.166.18.35    appcoiner.com:80    GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
32-1424    15749    0/108/2369131    W     3.26    17    0    0.0    2.09    55452.02     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
33-1424    17100    0/17/2359616    W     1.70    11    0    0.0    0.16    52564.23     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
34-1424    16310    0/162/2356424    W     3.95    15    0    0.0    2.68    55800.32     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
35-1424    16543    0/63/2326471    W     1.29    4    0    0.0    0.75    55028.80     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
36-1424    17101    0/18/2331624    W     2.05    14    0    0.0    0.21    53656.66     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
37-1424    17102    0/20/2314444    W     1.51    19    0    0.0    0.29    55684.29     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
38-1424    19665    0/1/2295814    W     0.00    3    0    0.0    0.00    52187.61     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
39-984    8727    1/69/1464486    G     0.68    2906097    450284    2.8    0.83    33844.50     74.63.153.4    suspensionrevolution.com:80    POST /dap/dap-clickbank-6.0.php HTTP/1.1
40-1424    19720    0/1/2277467    W     0.00    2    0    0.0    0.00    55864.93     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
41-1424    18141    0/6/2270838    W     0.62    14    0    0.0    0.02    54059.95     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
42-983    18177    1/49/1440183    G     0.63    2910665    450302    2.8    0.57    31224.74     74.63.153.4    suspensionrevolution.com:80    POST /dap/dap-clickbank-6.0.php HTTP/1.1
43-1424    16104    2/57/2242969    W     2.62    5    0    8.8    0.83    56170.39     54.202.7.147    appcoiner.com:80    GET /start-2/?utm_expid=111102625-1.-ThtNpCTSByWcbkMGdBOow.1&ho
44-1424    16547    0/28/2247277    W     3.84    5    0    0.0    0.31    53028.08     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
45-1424    15797    0/80/2225028    W     3.24    5    0    0.0    1.63    51333.94     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
46-1424    19721    0/1/2205346    W     0.00    2    0    0.0    0.00    52025.79     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
47-1424    18142    0/11/2207016    W     0.94    1    0    0.0    0.07    51355.07     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
48-1424    17104    0/137/2172322    W     1.28    7    0    0.0    2.32    49665.11     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
49-1424    16314    0/63/2168481    W     4.14    5    0    0.0    1.16    49191.04     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
50-1424    19763    0/0/2141243    W     2.41    12    0    0.0    0.00    49538.97     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
51-1424    17106    0/20/2137681    W     1.24    7    0    0.0    0.29    49973.70     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
52-1424    16549    0/34/2125106    W     1.99    7    0    0.0    0.50    50442.63     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
53-1424    17107    0/20/2109740    W     2.18    2    0    0.0    0.31    48074.92     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
54-1424    18143    0/4/2087977    W     1.21    8    0    0.0    0.00    49243.64     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
55-1424    17114    0/30/2062106    W     0.34    17    0    0.0    0.46    48605.36     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
56-1424    17115    0/19/2064562    W     2.07    0    0    0.0    0.30    47600.46     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
57-1424    16569    0/41/2051051    W     3.50    8    0    0.0    0.54    47547.57     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
58-1424    17116    0/28/2023150    W     1.28    4    0    0.0    0.42    49170.14     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
59-1424    17117    0/30/2010767    W     1.41    1    0    0.0    0.51    47681.03     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
60-1424    17118    0/17/1999913    R     0.05    53    5    0.0    0.26    46914.84     65.30.135.196       
61-1424    16572    0/35/1978028    W     2.73    16    0    0.0    0.45    45848.82     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
62-1424    16573    0/27/1957566    W     1.60    0    0    0.0    0.45    46768.01     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
63-1424    16574    0/43/1936669    W     2.37    3    0    0.0    0.54    43520.07     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
64-1424    16575    0/28/1922381    W     1.54    1    0    0.0    0.33    45007.49     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
65-1424    16576    0/32/1903916    W     2.15    13    0    0.0    0.73    45117.83     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
66-1424    17119    0/28/1878566    W     1.18    6    0    0.0    0.45    44448.25     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
67-1424    16578    1/39/1869043    K     2.01    0    0    1.2    0.53    44966.25     114.79.47.51    suspensionrevolution.com:80    GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
68-1424    16579    0/37/1841958    W     2.59    5    0    0.0    0.48    44262.26     72.5.231.11    appcoiner.com:80    GET /?hopc2s=nakt123 HTTP/1.1
```

This is my TOP output:

```
root@ns513521 [~]# top
top - 08:21:31 up 153 days,  3:51,  1 user,  load average: 0.15, 0.27, 0.51
Tasks: 230 total,  2 running, 227 sleeping,  0 stopped,  1 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.4%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32855908k total, 25102984k used,  7752924k free,  886004k buffers
Swap:  1569780k total,  63984k used,  1505796k free, 21254784k cached
```

This is my ioStat output:

```
Device:  tps  Blk_read/s  Blk_wrtn/s  Blk_read  Blk_wrtn
sda  21.99  1476.57  549.50 19540299168 7271856568
sdb  19.53  982.85  549.49 13006647390 7271718616
sdc  19.46  978.26  549.49 12945853934 7271718616
md2  9.78  492.22  399.94 6513868322 5292584264
md1  20.05  27.80  140.15  367920858 1854711136
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to reflect exactly *which* linux you're running -- different builds are subject to different bugs

Comment: Have you installed other packages or made new system-wide changes recently?

Comment: Server information is :Linux CentOS 6 Apache 2.4 PHP 5.5. No, I don't recall adding any new packages or made any system-wide changes. Could it be due to huge traffic surges?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use sar, e.g. something like this :

```
sar -q -s 00:00:00 -e 11:59:59 -f /var/log/sa/sa`date +%d | awk '{printf "%02d", $1 - 1}'`
```